# Set default value for multiple checkbox subgroups

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox, default

How to set default selected checkboxes when using "sub-groups" of checkboxes? You can achieve the so-called "sub-groups" by having a nested array for `'options'` attribute. I want to have all checkboxes selected by default.

```php
echo $this->Form->input('fooBar', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => false,
    'class' => 'inlineBlock',
    'options' => [
        'Foo' => [0 => 'Yes', 1 => 'No' ]
        'Bar' => [0 => 'One', 1 => 'Two', 2 => 'Three']
]]);
```

I've tried by setting

`'selected' => [0 => [0, 1], 0 => [0, 1, 2]]`

and

`'checked' => true`

but no luck.
If I check them manually and than submit the form, CakePHP generates URL parameters as if there were no "sub-groups", e.g.:

`'options' => [0 => 'Yes', 1 => 'No' ]`

which is the same behaviour as if I set

`'default' => [1, 2, 3]`

Is it even possible to set selected checkboxes of **individual** checkbox "sub-groups"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'val' attributes like below :

```
                    <?= $this->Form->control("themes._ids", [
                        "label" => false,
                        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                        "val" => [1, 2, 3]
                    ]) ?>
```

Reference [API Doc](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_select)